# Need help creating XML Document with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am having trouble creating an XML document using LINQ.

The XML file I need to create has a root element of "ClinicalDocument".

The XML needs to be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"
xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc"
xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">

<!-- Rest of the document here. -->

</ClinicalDocument>
```

The code I have in trying to do this is

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XDeclaration dec = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(dec,null);
XElement cDoc = new XElement("ClinicalDocumnet");
xDoc.Add(cDoc);
cDoc.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName));
cDoc.Add(new XAttribute("xmlns","urn:hl7-org:v3"));
cDoc.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "stdc","urn:hl7-org:sdtc"));
cDoc.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "voc","urn:hl7-org:v3/voc"));
xDoc.Save("C:\\test\\test.xml");
```

I get an exception when trying to save the file.

> {"The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'urn:hl7-org:v3' within the same start element tag."}

Answer (score 2):

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:hl7-org:v3";

xDoc = new XDocument(dec, null);
cDoc = new XElement(ns + "ClinicalDocument");
xDoc.Add(cDoc);

cDoc.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
cDoc.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "stdc","urn:hl7-org:sdtc"));
cDoc.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "voc","urn:hl7-org:v3/voc"));
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you create `xsi` and then do [`xsi.NamespaceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.namespacename(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of simply doing the string directly, as with `stdc` and `voc`?

Comment: No, just a copy-paste for the question.

Comment: Inside the document I need to use the xsi namespace